# How to query database inside a bootstrap modal (or dialog box) and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

In my view, I am querying and displaying all the rows from the database. All the rows are displayed fine except the problem comes in when i use a bootstrap modal (or bootstrap dialog box). I want to display the email for each query using modal (the dialog box) but the problem is that in each query the email in the first row of the table is the one that is being displayed for all the other queries...

what might i have done wrong here.    thnx

my View

```
<?php
foreach($query as $row)
{ ?>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Title of the data from the database
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">User email for this user</h4>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <?php echo $row->email?><!--this is where my problem is-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using duplicated id="myModal" therefore your button always open the same modal.
You can try to create unique Modal IDs and buttons for each of your rows. You can use row ID or something similar to differentiate

For example:

```
<button ... data-target="#myModal-<?php echo $row->id;?>">
...
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<?php echo $row->id;?>">
  ...
```